# Java Exceptions and Catch Clause

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Here is some simple code I was writing for a test.
I know that I can't define a catch block that catches a checked exception that the code in the try block doesn't declare to throw (because it would contain unreachable statements and the compiler won't let me).

So, what is happening here exactly? (java.io.InvalidClassException is a subclass of Exception and so it's a checked exception.)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test {

  public void copy()  {
    try (InputStream is=new FileInputStream("file1");
         OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("file2");) {
      byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
      int bytesRead=0;
      while ((bytesRead=is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
      }
    }
    catch (java.io.InvalidClassException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

The code compiles fine... How is that possible??

Comment: You declare the method to *throw* an exception if you **don't** *catch* it. You caught possible (checked) exceptions, so your method can never throw them.

Comment: could you post your error message?

Comment: `InvalidClassException` extends `IOException`. You are using methods that throw `IOException`. Therefore it is possible that an `InvalidClassException` could be thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`is.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29) declares that it throws `IOException`. [`InvalidClassException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InvalidClassException.html) extends `IOException`. Therefore as far as your code knows, it is possible that `is.read()` could throw an `InvalidClassException`. So you are allowed to try and catch it.

Comment: It is also important to notice that inverting the 2 `catch` clauses would produce the "unreachable statement" error.

Answer (score 1):

`InvalidClassException` is a subtype of `IOException`, which can be thrown by `InputStream#read()` and `OutpuStream#write()` methods, so try-catch block is valid here.